# Python - Pandas - What is the exact formula for percentile calculation by describe() method?

Tags: python, pandas, percentile, describe

Could someone please explain how percentiles are calculated by describe() method.

Different sources explained this using different approaches. What is the exact way of calculation?

For example, consider the following code:

```
l=[10,13,15,19,21,25]
s=pd.Series(l)
s.describe()
```

Output is:

```
count     6.000000
mean     17.166667
std       5.528713
min      10.000000
**25%      13.500000**
50%      17.000000
75%      20.500000
max      25.000000
```

Could someone please explain how 25%(Q1) is calculated ?

Comment: you know the basic concept of percentiles? you just want to know how pandas calculates this right?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d6c258691dfa01b300bb3d904df3e3e7dabe55cc/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1590

Comment: I believe you are looking for `pandas.Series.quantile()` https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d6c258691dfa01b300bb3d904df3e3e7dabe55cc/pandas/core/series.py#L2546

Comment: @MrIrrelevant Yes!

Comment: what are those weird ** doing?

Comment: @MrIrrelevant I tried to keep the font "Bold" :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an explanation on: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html

the df.quantile() function has several parameters that can be used to calculate the quantiles in different Interpolations. for df.describe() the default used appears to be linear as seen here:

```
s.quantile([.25, .5, .75], interpolation="linear")
```

which gives:

```
0.25    13.5
0.50    17.0
0.75    20.5
```

you can also use:

```
s.quantile([.25, .5, .75], interpolation="nearest")
```

to get:

```
0.25    13
0.50    15
0.75    21
```

"nearest" was the one I was expecting too.
With respect to the doc, the formula for linear is:

**linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.**

Comment: @hANDEEP V does this solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) documentation (by default the interpolation is linear):

> linear: i + (j - i) * (x-i)/(j-i)
>
> where (x-i)/(j-i) is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i > j.

`i` is obtained by  `interpolation='lower'` and `j` by  `interpolation='higher'`

So here `i = 13 ; j = 15 ; (x-i)/(j-i) = 0.25`:

```
13 + (15 - 13) * 0.25 = 13.5
```

Comment: You have assumed i=13 and j=15, whereas as per the documentation quoted by you, i > j. Could you please explain ?

Comment: @SANDEEPV I have to say the explanation is not very clear but it also says `lower: i` and `higher: j` and using those interpolations on your Series give those respective numbers. Maybe the `i > j` is meant as a `i → j`?